# Check if SELECT statement conditions are true

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
string  test = "SELECT count(*) FROM table where email=@email AND active=@active";
```

Hello, is it possible using C# to check if both of the conditions are true or if only one of them is true?

```
int count = testCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried using the code above but i am not sure i understand how it works.. will count be 1 only if both conditions are true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
string test = "
    select COUNT(*) from(
        select case when (SELECT count(*) FROM table where email=@email AND active=@active)>0 then 1 else null end Num
        union all
        select case when (SELECT count(*) FROM table where email=@email OR active=@active)>0 then 1 else null end Num
    )x where Num is not null"
```

which returns 2 if both the conditions are true, 1 if any one of them is true and 0 if both are false.

And use `ExecuteScalar()`  instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` (which returns number of rows effected).

```
i.e. int count  = (Int32)testCMD.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: i will try this and come back.. seems to be what i am looking for .. thanks

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will returns number of rows affected, it is not the value that your Query returns. so only by using above Query will not solve OPs problem. with ExecuteScalar method with above Query will give  what OP wanted

Comment: i accepted this as the answer since it directly solved my problem.. thanks for helping out

Answer (score 2):

Count will return the number of results where both conditions are true. If you want to check one or the other then use OR instead of AND.

[Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> will count be 1 only if both conditions are true ?

**Yes**. You are using `AND` operator in your query.

> is it possible using C# to check if both of the conditions are true or
>   if only one of them is true?

With the above query, **No**. You can't. You need to either create two different queries for each parameter, or use `OR` operator inplace of `AND` to see if either of the condition is true. But with `OR` you can't be sure which one is true.